question on differing views from scholars like Assim, Muftimenk, Yassir Qadhi etc
As someone deeply interested in comparative religion and Islam, I often struggle with the conflicting interpretations presented by different scholars, especially on practical matters. Scholars like Asim emphasize strict rules that seem overly rigid and out of touch with real life—discouraging any friendships with non-Muslims, advising not to invite or be invited by “kafirs,” and even suggesting complete disassociation from family members who leave Islam. He extends this rigidity to everyday family interactions, such as limiting contact with female cousins to only a quick “hi,” even in close-knit families where this feels unnatural. These interpretations sometimes feel not only unrealistic but also alienating; many Muslims I know, including those in business partnerships with non-Muslims, live without issue or conflict. Following such a strict view feels impractical and even drives me farther from Islam because it’s difficult to align with how people actually live.
Yet, other scholars interpret these principles differently, with allowances for respectful friendships, acknowledging good influences, and recognizing the practical realities of family bonds and mixed communities. This approach seems more in line with everyday life, but choosing it can lead to being labeled as a “modernist,” which I don’t want to be seen as.
I genuinely want to understand Islam’s core teachings, but these contradictions leave me wondering: How can I know which interpretation aligns best with true Islamic principles, especially when scholars offer such conflicting guidance on essential social matters? And if Islam is meant to provide clear moral direction, why do these critical issues—ones that impact everyday relationships and decisions—have so much room for debate?

Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and the SE model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

A simple answer is that while the texts of Islam might be divine, the interpretation might is human. So everybody interprets according to their environment, life experience, education, etc.. Further, in case there are different options some would take the most strict while others the most lenient option. However, at the end it depends on the individual, whether such strictness or lenience is necessary.

Assalamu'alaekum akhi, hope you're doing well and I got your question and my answer could be a bit longer but Inshallah it will help you I will try my best.
Okay so first of All look no matter who is there like scholars like Shaykh Assim, Yasir Qadhi, Mufti Ismail Menk they all are from the same school of methodology and jurisprudence and the problems that you are facing it could be because of their culture and climate they are living in and it is totally normal because one person is in America he have to look their of how to encourage Muslims to unite another is in totally different ethnistic culture like Shaykh Assim he is in Saudi Arabia it is easy for him to say the things like This is totally man-made and haraam in Islam while Shaykh Yasir will deal a bit differently to address the best to their "American-fellows" which is a democratic federalists state and the bureaucracy is islamophobic too in the management slogans like "Islam is Cance"(Naudhubillah) is common or terroristic blunder issues it is all there, so he have to look in that manner to form the Islamic climate among Muslims their to try best to cope the things up while for shaykh assim there is not even a single problem for him because he knows the management of Saudi State, so hope you got my point and Shaykh Menk or Mufti Menk idk much but still he is from Zimbabwe that's where he is doing the work of Islam May Allah make it easy for him and he is also as I have told you it's a totally different country with different laws that's why by seeing the overall state policies and Islamic interpretations became a bit different and it's natural in this era as we are in democratical, capitalistic and very evil times May Allah make it easy for us to establish his laws and Shar'ia.
So now I have told you why it happens with different Islamic interpretations and now in last end I will tell you how to deal with them.
So the most rooted and most correct way of Islam to deal with these situations is from the "Dalail way" like just see the citations and references that they are quoting as they will also help you to understand the Islamic studies a bit like if Shaykh Assim is saying it is totally prohibited to even go with a lenient "Hie" to cousin so just check the reference of what they are doing like Prophet SAW said in Muwatta Imam Malik there is a hadith that it has asked to Prophet that can we respond to the greetings of Salam to any lady he SAW said "yes you can" and then it has asked can we greet with salam to any lady so he SAW said "as for me I dislike this" so you can see by this narration of Muwatta Malik that yes indeed prophet disliked these kinds of contacts with Non-Mahrams except if it is necessary so by this I hope you got your reference and also there is a hadith in Bukhari or in Sahih Muslim that when people of Madinah came to Prophet SAW there were 2 to 3 ladies too so he (SAW) refused to pledge the allegiance with them and then he SAW said that "I have never ever touched any non-mahram lady before and I will not" so you can see by this evidence that how he was SAW in dealing with other women so everytime YOU SEE A DIFFERENT INTERPRETATION TRY TO LOOK AFTER THAT WHAT THEY ARE QUOTING AND CITING AS A REFERENCE LIKE WHICH QURAN'S VERSE OR AHADITH OF WHAT THEY ARE QUOTING AND READ IT BY YOURSELF TOO SO THAT YOU CAN UNDERSTAND THAT YES IT IS BETTER"
And in the end another benefit that you will get by this is the real Islamic knowledge as the Prophet SAW said that "It is obligatory upon every Muslim to achieve knowledge"(Sahih Muslim) so it will help you to follow the prophet this order too and it will help you to understand the realm of Islam in the light of Qur'an and Sunnah which is more beneficial than to understand it from different background scholars and why they interpret different a bit from other just a bit I have told you that too, hope it helps you JazakALlah khayr, rest Allah knows best.
